# How to select only non empty cells in a column using applescript

Tags: excel, macos, automation, applescript, excel-automation

i want to select only non empty cells in a column using applescript.

A B C D

1

2

3

4

In the above scenario i want know the range of non empty cells of column A that is 1,2,3,4.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It will be good to have look at the code where you are stuck or getting error.
However as per my understanding try using below code:

Application.Intersect(Range("A:D"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Select